# Invalid Syntax error?

Tags: python

I'm new at Python and tried writing a basic script.
I'm trying to print out all the letters of the alphabet, and I keep getting Invalid Syntax.

```
letter = ord('a')
while letter != ord('z')
    print(chr(letter))
    letter = letter + 1
```

Here's the first error log:

```
while letter != ord('z')
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It seemed that Python doesn't like closing parentheses, so when I removed it, it gave me this:

```
print(chr(letter))
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I couldn't do anything to fix this one, so I tried removing the line entirely. It then gave me this:

```
letter = letter + 1
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have no idea what I'm doing at this point, and only after deleting the entire script altogether was Python finally happy.
How do I fix the script so it doesn't get any more Invalid Syntaxes?

Comment: You’re missing the colon at the end of the `while` line.

Comment: Don't put "RESOLVED" or things like that in the title, instead accept an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a colon at the end of your while loop, to let Python know it's a block.

```
while letter != ord('z'):
    <rest of your code here>
```

Also, right now you seem to have the start of the while loop indented and none of the rest, when you want the opposite: all the code to be run in the while loop should be indented, but the header shouldn't be.

As a side note, your `ord` and `chr` strategy is totally valid but probably more complicated than necessary. In Python, a for loop can iterate through a string as well as a range of numbers. So you can say

```
for character in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
    print(character)
```

A shorter way to get that alphabet string is

```
import string
string.lowercase
```

Comment: Thanks, I somehow missed that!

Comment: Edited to include some info on how this can be done more easily in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Missing the colon in end `while` loop.

```
 letter = ord('a')
 while letter != ord('z'):
       print(chr(letter)) 
       letter += 1
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed something that obvious :/ Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntax error because the + sign is counted as a variable when you leave it by itself. It should be like this

```
x = input("ecrit ton premier nomber :")
z = input("ecrit ton Processus :")
y = input("ecrit ton deuxieme nombre :")
if z == "+":
    print(x+y)
```

x and y are also treated as strings so it won't actually add them together, it'll just put them next to each other. Example: if x is 5 and y is 6, the output will be 56 and not 11. This can be fixed by declaring the input as an integer.

```
x = int(input("ecrit ton premier nomber :"))
z = input("ecrit ton Processus :")
y = int(input("ecrit ton deuxieme nombre :"))
if z == "+":
    print(x+y)
```